How to build WHERE condition based on a calculated field?
I have this query that pulls data from the inventory bin location and a user defined field that shows the max number of pallets per warehouse.
My data:
   Bin Code     Max Pallets     Total Pallets    Available
   000-AA-001   34              30               4
   000-BB-001   24              18               6
   000-CC-001   12              14               -2

My query:
SELECT T0."BinCode", T0."U_TRX_MaxPallets" AS "Max Pallets",
SUM(NDIV0(T1."OnHandQty", (T2."U_TRX_Ti" * T2."U_TRX_Hi"))) AS "Total Pallets", T0."U_TRX_MaxPallets" - SUM(NDIV0(T1."OnHandQty", (T2."U_TRX_Ti" * T2."U_TRX_Hi"))) AS "Available"
FROM OBIN T0  INNER JOIN OIBQ T1 ON T0."AbsEntry" = T1."BinAbs"  
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
WHERE T1."OnHandQty"  <> 0 AND  T1."WhsCode" ='000' AND SUBSTRING(T0."BinCode",5,1) <> 'R' AND SUBSTRING(T0."BinCode",5,1) <> 'P' AND SUBSTRING(T0."BinCode",1,11) <> '000-OFFICE' AND SUBSTRING(T0."BinCode",1,8) <> '000-OTBD' AND "Available" > 0
GROUP BY T0."BinCode", T0."U_TRX_MaxPallets"
ORDER BY T0."BinCode"

The end result is I need all bin codes where the available > 0.
I added a column called Total, and removed all references to Bin.
It gives me an error message when I remove the T0."U_TRX_MaxPallets" from the group by clause.
SELECT 'Total' AS "Total", T0."U_TRX_MaxPallets" AS "Max Pallets",
SUM(NDIV0(T1."OnHandQty", (T2."U_TRX_Ti" * T2."U_TRX_Hi"))) AS "Total Pallets", T0."U_TRX_MaxPallets" - SUM(NDIV0(T1."OnHandQty", (T2."U_TRX_Ti" * T2."U_TRX_Hi"))) AS "Available"
FROM OBIN T0  INNER JOIN OIBQ T1 ON T0."AbsEntry" = T1."BinAbs"  
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
WHERE T1."OnHandQty"  <> 0 AND  T1."WhsCode" ='000' AND SUBSTRING(T0."BinCode",5,1) <> 'R' AND SUBSTRING(T0."BinCode",5,1) <> 'P' AND SUBSTRING(T0."BinCode",1,11) <> '000-OFFICE' AND SUBSTRING(T0."BinCode",1,8) <> '000-OTBD'
GROUP BY 'Total', T0."U_TRX_MaxPallets"


So people take the time to edit what I said since I said in wrong, but can't provide an answer?
Thanks anyway for the help or just the criticism of my message...

People are taking the time to improve your question, so that chances increase to actually get it answered by people who know. This is not criticism. This is part of a constructive and healthy culture.

If you simply would like to filter for available > 0, you can do so by using a nested select statement or the HAVING clause.
Option 1:
SELECT *
FROM
( 
    <INSERT YOUR QUERY HERE>
)
WHERE "Available" > 0

Option 2:
<INSERT YOUR QUERY HERE>
HAVING T0."U_TRX_MaxPallets" - SUM(NDIV0(T1."OnHandQty", (T2."U_TRX_Ti" * T2."U_TRX_Hi"))) > 0

